# allocation failed: out of vmalloc space - use vmalloc=<size> to increase size

Tags: centos, dmesg

I have a problem with the following error appearing upon sending a dmesg command to my server:

```
allocation failed: out of vmalloc space - use vmalloc=<size> to increase size.
```

How do I increase vmalloc size?

Here are some server specs:

```
root@h3 [~]# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         16248        753      15494          0        142        244
-/+ buffers/cache:        366      15881
Swap:         8001          0       8001


root@h3 [~]# uname -a
Linux h3.------ 2.6.18-308.20.1.el5PAE #1 SMP Tue Nov 13 11:03:25 EST 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux


root@h3 [~]# cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:     16638140 kB
MemFree:      15858856 kB
Buffers:        145560 kB
Cached:         250732 kB
SwapCached:          0 kB
Active:         492580 kB
Inactive:       181376 kB
HighTotal:    15859644 kB
HighFree:     15269436 kB
LowTotal:       778496 kB
LowFree:        589420 kB
SwapTotal:     8193140 kB
SwapFree:      8193140 kB
Dirty:              96 kB
Writeback:           0 kB
AnonPages:      277692 kB
Mapped:          16864 kB
Slab:            39236 kB
PageTables:       3516 kB
NFS_Unstable:        0 kB
Bounce:              0 kB
CommitLimit:  16512208 kB
Committed_AS:   688060 kB
VmallocTotal:   116728 kB
VmallocUsed:     55576 kB
VmallocChunk:    17604 kB
HugePages_Total:     0
HugePages_Free:      0
HugePages_Rsvd:      0
Hugepagesize:     2048 kB
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you, or anyone else, done any memory tuning on this system? Those numbers look *very* strange. Your system is very starved for low memory and using hardly any high memory.

Comment: No memory tuning has been made to this system at all. It is all out of the box, with CentOS installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by adding vmalloc=512M to the grub loader and then restarted the server. Now looks like vmalloc changed to:

> VmallocTotal:  509944 kB 
>   VmallocUsed:   63788 kB 
>   VmallocChunk:  395572 kB

And errors disappeared.